# Understanding vieta jumping.

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, vieta-jumping

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab + 1$ divides $a^2 + b^2$. Show that $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}$$
is the square of an integer.

I have a few questions about the proof. First here it is ,

Assume $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}=k$$ is not a perfect square. Rearranging, we get a quadratic in $a$
$$a^2 −kb·a+(b^2 −k)=0. \quad (*)$$
Clearly $(*)$ has two solution the first one is $a$ so let the second be $s$. Then by Vieta we have $$s=kb-a=\frac{b^2-k}{a}$$  The first equation shows $s$ is an integer, and from $*$ $s$ is positive.

Now since $*$ symmetric we can assume $a>b$ Ignore $a=b$ because it gives a perfect square. Hence $s<a$ so we have a descent. Right?

In my book the author said this *So, do we have a descent? If we repeat the process of (s, b), we would get a quadratic in s, and we pick the second root. Do you see an issue?* But I don’t really see any issue.

Comment: I suppose there is error in the proof. It is still necessary to show 
that $s$ is positive. Both $a+s=kb$ and $as=b^2-k$ lead to 
$s=\frac{b^3-a}{ab+1}$, which can be negative.

Comment: No, since $s^2+b^2/sb+1=k>0$ we get that $s$ is positive.@IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: OK, $sb+1>0 \Rightarrow sb > -1$. $s,b$ are integer then $sb\geq 0$. Then $s=0$ or $s>0$. $s=0$ gives $b^2=k$, then $k$ is perfect square. This case is also part of solution.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, we assumed that there is a smallest positive integer $a$ such that $k$ is not a perfect square. Using the quadratic you gave, if we have a root such that $a$ is not equal to $b$, then we will always be able to find a root smaller than $a$ that fits the requirements. However, this contradicts our assumption that $a$ was minimal. Thus, $k$ must be a perfect square.

This is similar to the method of descent, where we will always find a smaller root that fits the requirements. However, since there is a smallest positive integer, it is not possible to do this over and over, which shows that there are no solutions with $k$ not a perfect square.

Comment: I saw another question which asks to show that actually $k=\gcd(a,b)$ would you please link an answer because I think the solution is too easy to post a whole question in MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $ab+1$ divides $a^2+b^2$. Show that $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$ is the square of an integer (perfect square).

Expression $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$ is symmetric with respect to $a$ and
$b$, then without loss of generality we can suppose $a\geq b$.

Let consider first case $a=b$. Then
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=\frac{2a^2}{a^2+1}=2-\frac{2}{a^2+1}$$ This
expression can be integer at integer positive $a$ only if $a=1$, then
$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=1$$ is perfect square.

Now consider case $a>b$. Let suppose that $a$ is minimum positive
integer such that exists positive integer $b<a$ such that
$\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is integer but is not perfect square. Let
consider expression $$s=\frac{b^3-a}{ab+1}$$
$$s=\frac{b^3-a}{ab+1}=b\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}-a\Rightarrow s\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$s=\frac{b^3-a}{ab+1}>-\frac{a}{ab+1}\geq-\frac{a}{a+1}>-1$$ $$s>-1 
\land s\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow s\geq 0$$ $$s=0\Rightarrow 
a=b^3\Rightarrow \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=b^2$$ which contradicts to the fact
that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is not perfect square. Then $s>0$.
$$s=\frac{b^3-a}{ab+1}<\frac{b^3}{b^2}=b$$ Let consider expression
$$\frac{b^2+s^2}{bs+1}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$$ Then $b$ is positive
integer such that exists positive integer $s<b$ such that
$\frac{b^2+s^2}{bs+1}$ is integer but is not perfect square. Then $b<a$ contradicts with the fact that $a$ is minimum positive integer with such
property. Then there is no minimum positive integer with such property,
then there is no positive integers $a,b$ with such property.